# Android getFileDir Location

Tags: android, android-emulator

In android, I am trying to save the XML file locally.

I am using the below syntax to do it

```
File myFile = new File(getFilesDir()+"/loginUser.xml");
myFile.createNewFile();
```

It is working fine in emulator as well as device.

Now my question is what is the path this `getFilesDir()` in System(in Emulator)

Comment: Open DDMS -> File explorer -> look for `/data/data/<app_package_name>/files/`

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal.

It can depend on the system but generally files are stored somewhere in `/data/data`.. in separate directories for each app.